# Experience with using the API to sync salesforce data to local DB?

Tags: rest-api, sync, data-protection-and-privacy

I currently use REST API calls whenever I need to get data from and store data to salesforce.
I frequently run into API limit restrictions (= too many requests)

So I would like a solution where I have the data in my own DB so I can make as many queries as I want. I would still post changes to the API and I would have a job that regularly pulls the latest changes from the API:

e.g. `SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE SystemModStamp >= : OneHourAgo`

Who does something similar and what are potential pitfalls?

Does it cause any issues with data privacy when you also do this for customers salesforce data? i.e. you have their token and pull their data to you database?

Comment: Please take a look at [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) decision guide, it covers the options.

Comment: @identigral I don't think this is possible since we only have the customers access/refresh token for the REST api. So I need a solution that's building on that

Comment: ...and have a look at [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) while you're at it.